# PHP: Class Scope - external class best practice?

Tags: php, class, scope

I'm pretty new to classes.

I am using a PDO connection, and all is well so far. I can login/logout, display the users information on the screen. all updates inserts etc all works. I have a general query about the strcuture of my website before i go any further.

**My main question is**,

Is it better to pass the variables that i need into the methods that i call (Most use the user_id, so i would be calling $user -> user_id in most method calls), but then how should i contact an external method such as a method from the $user object?

Or is it better to pass the $user object when creating a new $task object?

**See below for code snippets and examples**

I dont want to start from scratch, so extending BaseModel will be my way forward with this project...

I have a similar setup to the below;

```
//main class

class BaseModel(){
//configure db here $db
//subclasses can use as self:$db
//there is if($db doesnt exist).. to stop multiple connection threads being 
//created when multiple objects are created.
}

//...and I have 2 subclasses

class User Extends BaseModel
//create new user object, confirm login details (cookie, ip etc)
//returns user object as array.
}


class Tasks Extends BaseModel

//do various cleanup tasks
}
```

In the main script I create a new instance of each:

```
$user = new User();
$task = new Task();
```

If i want to call the redirect task (PHP's header("Location:...) i can include the user_id in the method call;

```
$task -> redirect($user -> user_id, "newloc.php")
```

this will forward the user to the requested page, and also logs it in the database with the user id (useful while in development mode to eradicate too many page loops).

Obviously this is pretty simple, however how about if I want to communicate with the $user class directly within the $task class? I have found that I can instead create a $task object passing the $user object;

```
$task = new Task($user);
```

In my tests I have found that i can then access the $user data and methods (such as $this -> user->user_id), and allows me to access the methods in there, for example;

(Note: i dont log the user redirects. this is the simplest example i can think of);

```
$task -> redirect("newurl.php");

//within redirect
public function redirect($url){
$this -> user -> increaseTotalRedirects();
```

*The system is obviously much more complicated than this. the example in this post is literally just an example to get my point across*

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Welcome. I appreciate your effort in writing a "complete" question. Yet you may want to highlight your actual question and maybe drop irrelevant code, to encourage people to read to the end.

Comment: Thanks, @Zsolt Szilagy i have moved the question to the top of the post and labelled it clearly. The snippets of code can now be read at the answerers discretion. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a protected class attribute like `$_user` in `Task` class like this:

```
class Task extends BaseModel
{
    protected $_user;

    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->_user = $user;
    }
}
```

and add a getter method of this attribute like this:

```
public function getUser()
{
    return $this->_user;
}
```

so you can use `User` class methods in `Task` class like this:

```
$this->getUser()->userMethod(); // this is a method in User class
```

Note: i declared $_user `protected` and not `private` because it can be accessible in all subclass of `Task` class (if you want to extends this class)